# Give "ID" to multiple columns

Tags: postgresql

Is there a native `postgresql` function that gives "IDs", based on the column.

```
column 1    column 2    id1    id2
aa          AA          1      1 
aa          BB          1      2 
bb          BB          2      2 
cc          BB          3      2
cc          CC          3      3  
dd          DD          4      4
```

I only want the "ID" to increment, when the value in the `column` changes. Otherwise, the "ID" should be the same.

Comment: You don't need a column, there is a functional dependency.

Comment: @wildplasser i want to add the "id" as a column though

Comment: It is nonsense, you can just enumerate them, maybe even put them in a view.

Comment: @wildplasser how would you know my whole programe and judge what is nonsense, based on the example I gave?! You have absolutely no idea how I will proceed from here on and/or what I need it for.

Comment: Maybe your wording is a bit vague. I meant: *storing* them makes no sense, since they are redundant. *computing* them (as expressions) is trivial. See my answer

Comment: @wildplasser As I said, I need it stored in a column :) With your code I can alter the column - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT o.column1, o.column2
        , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY column1) AS id1
        , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY column2) AS id2
FROM ordi o
        ;
```